# Why does summoning a falling block turn command blocks into stone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I used this command:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ 
{Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:
{Command:"/fill ~ ~-1 ~-1 ~ ~50 ~-1 redstone_block"},Passengers:
[{id:falling_block,Block:redstone_block,Time:1}]}
```

But instead of summoning a **command** block with the command stated, it summoned a falling **stone** block.

Using Minecraft 1.12.2

Comment: Try again with the spaces and linebreaks. That often messes up commands. And try without `TileEntityData` and `Passengers` first, shorter/simpler commands are easier to debug.

Comment: @FabianRöling What do you mean "with the spaces and linebreaks? I tried the command `/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ {Block:command_block,Time:1}` but it still summons a stone block

Comment: You put linebreaks into the command here, that either puts spaces into the command if you copy-paste it or does other weird thins. Better put everything in one line, don't worry, it will automatically create a scroll bar. Also, I can't test it right now, but try quotation marks around `command_block`.

Comment: @FabianRöling Nope didn't work still summoned as a stone block

Comment: I'll test it myself later today or tomorrow. The problem is that the wiki is already changed to 1.13, so it's hard to get 1.12 info out of it. Until then, try putting `minecraft:` in front of `command_block`, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: The old state of the wiki page: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Sand/BE&oldid=1107045

Comment: I pasted the same code into a command block in 1.12.2 and it did summon another command block, and then that block created a tower of redstone blocks (I assume that's the intended behavior). I didn't get any stone. Do you have any mods installed that could be interfering? Other active command blocks in the world could also interfere.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the command block does not think that you specified a block. Since the item value of 1 is a stone block, the command block defaulted to that block.